# Unable to search the Data into Datatable using Ajax - Codeigniter

Tags: php, ajax, codeigniter, datatable

Hi Everyone I am creating a web portal. I want to add display a datatable. I use Datatable plugin for this but I am facing some issue. please help me with this.

**This is my Contorller code**

```
public function fetchTeams() {
    $data = $this->Teams_model->getAllTeams();
    echo json_encode(array("data" => $data));
}
```

My HTML view

```
<div class="card-body">
    <table id="teamDatatable" class="display table table-bordered table-hover" width="100%">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Employee name</th>
                <th>Email</th>
                <th>Gender</th>
                <th>Salary</th>
                <th>City</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
    </table>
</div>
```

My Model

```
public function getAllTeams() {
    $query = $this->db->get("teams");
    return $query->result_array();
    $query1 = $this->db->get('Teams');
    $data1 = $query->num_rows();
    $response = array(
        "iTotalRecords" => $data1,
        "aaData" => $data
    );

    return $response;
}
```

My view[image]

My View [image]

No record [image]

Comment: What issue are you facing?

Comment: I am fetching Data from the Database, but I can not filter them. I am unable to search and I am not able to see total number of records.

Answer (score 1):

> Hope this helps Check my server side codeigniter script here 
>   [Server side datatable codeigniter](https://github.com/eboominathan/Simple-server-side-Datatables-in-Codeigniter)